# Combining PHP__autoload with Mollie_API_Autoloader class

Tags: php, autoload, mollie

Although I know it's not appropriate to ask for ready-to-use code, I do in this case, since I'm failing to find the solution.

Trying to use native PHP __autoload function along with the Mollie_API_Autoloader class:

```
class Mollie_API_Autoloader
{
/**
 * @param string $class_name
 */
public static function autoload ($class_name)
{
    if (strpos($class_name, "Mollie_") === 0)
    {
        $file_name = str_replace("_", "/", $class_name);
        $file_name = realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . 
"/../../{$file_name}.php");

        if ($file_name !== false)
        {
            require $file_name;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * @return bool
 */
public static function register ()
{
    return spl_autoload_register(array(__CLASS__, "autoload"));
}

/**
 * @return bool
 */
public static function unregister ()
{
    return spl_autoload_unregister(array(__CLASS__, "autoload"));
}
}

Mollie_API_Autoloader::register();
```

The Mollie autoloader class affects the proper functioning of the native PHP __autoload class. Can't seem to combine these. How'd I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`__autoload()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.autoload.php) is deprecated, it was replaced by [`spl_autoloader_register()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) many years ago (on PHP 5.1.2).

They cannot work together. `__autoload()` is limited and all it does, `spl_autoloader_register()` does better.

Since the class you posted already uses `spl_autoload_register()`, all you have to do is to call

```
Mollie_API_Autoloader::register()
```

somewhere in your boostrap code.

If your existing code uses `__autoload()` you can easily change it to use `spl_autoload_register()`. Just rename the `__autoload` function to something else (let's say `old_autoloader`) and add `spl_autoload_register('old_autoloader');` after its definition.

Check [Example #1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php#refsect1-function.spl-autoload-register-examples) on the documentation of [`spl_autoload_register()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) for an example.